# Prevent app from crashing

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I've a C# WPF application that throws following error message and crashes:

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I then added following exception handlers in the code. And also added following line of code in the start of the method which was throwing above exception.

```
throw new System.AccessViolationException();
```

Exception handlers are now getting executed on clicking the app exe on my local machine when above exception occurs, but the app still crashes. I need to be able to prevent the app from crashing. Not sure how do I do that?

```
application.DispatcherUnhandledException += ApplicationDispatcherUnhandledException;

TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;


AppDomain currentAppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentAppDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler
                        (UnhandledExceptionHandler);
```

Thanks.

Comment: By fixing the Access Violation.

Comment: The **stack trace** of the exception will surely tell you _where_ the exception occured. Check that code, you are obviously doing something wrong that's corrupting your memory (maybe some native or p/invoke call). Try to fix that. We can't tell what you're doing wrong without seeing the (_relevant_) code.

Comment: You dont want it to crash, wrap it in `try catch`, but still it wont fix your issue.

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803168/how-do-i-continue-running-after-an-unhandled-exception

Comment: Can you show the content of `ApplicationDispatcherUnhandledException`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify what part of code is throwing that exception. I bet it is some external unmanged library.

If you cannot repair that library, you can follow instructions on MSDN:

[AccessViolationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

**AccessViolationException and try/catch blocks**

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, AccessViolationException
>   exceptions thrown by the common language runtime are not handled by
>   the catch statement in a structured exception handler if the exception
>   occurs outside of the memory reserved by the common language runtime.
>   To handle such an AccessViolationException exception, you should apply
>   the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute attribute to the
>   method in which the exception is thrown. This change does not affect
>   AccessViolationException exceptions thrown by user code, which can
>   continue to be caught by a catch statement. For code written for
>   previous versions of the .NET Framework that you want to recompile and
>   run without modification on the .NET Framework 4, you can add the
>    element to your app's
>   configuration file. Note that you can also receive notification of the
>   exceptions if you have defined a handler for the
>   AppDomain.FirstChanceException or AppDomain.UnhandledException event.

Comment: Thanks.Would this prevent app from crashing?