# Instantiating a type crashes my Win32/.NET app

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to instantiate a type implementing IDisposable belonging a third-party assembly using Activator.CreateInstance(), but the call returns null because the type's constructor throws an exception due to some missing configuration that I can do nothing about.  My code consists of a Win32 process which loads a .NET plugin via COM, and this plugin performs all the reflection and instantiation of third-party types. The plugin loads third party assemblies into their own assembly load context, and I use this context as reflection only contexts, which I *think* is the correct way to do it.

However, the type's Dispose method is being called even though the instantiation failed, throwing a NullReferenceException, which crashes my entire process and I have no idea why. I'm struggling to debug because it seems there could be a whole bunch of causes like an assembly load context issue (I don't think it is) or a bug in the third party assembly. Either way, it shouldn't bring my app down in the way it does. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you complaining that your own code calls Dispose on a null variable, or that third party code does that?

Comment: I have no idea whose code is calling Dispose to be honest! The stack trace shows the destructor of the type being called, but again, I don't know why considering the instantiation failed.

Comment: There are no descturtors in C#, there are finalizers, and those [are called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/188722/11683). If the type disposes its own things in its own finalizer without considering if they may be null, then there is nothing you can do apart from ignoring the exception.

Comment: Thanks for that. I still don't know why it brings our application down.

Comment: Check Event View or Last Window Error to get more info.

Comment: Because [that is what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7821957/11683) when you have unhandled exceptions?