# C# unable to catch all exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, mono, try-catch

I'm writing a C# application (in Linux with mono but it shouldn't matter) and I am programming with duplicati dlls. I want that the program never crashes so I tried to catch every exception. The Problem now is that an exception is thrown and I can't catch it. Maybe from a thread?!?

Sidenote: Just for testing purposes I intentionally tried to backup to a Location where I don't have permission. If I give permission, then I get no error.

The code Looks like the following:

```
try {
    Interface i = new Interface(backend, options);
    result = i.Backup(folders.ToArray());
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Write to log.
    //Here is no throw; !!
}
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
Error : System.Exception: Failed to retrieve file listing: Access to the path "/home/pi/test" is denied. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/home/pi/test" is denied.
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Duplicati.Library.Backend.File.List () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Duplicati.Library.Main.BackendWrapper.ListInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Duplicati.Library.Main.BackendWrapper.ListInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Why am I unable to catch all exceptions? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not directly related: some of exceptions are more exceptional than others - like StackOverflow... Back to question - stack does not really correspond to code shown - so very hard to suggest anything, but indeed exceptions thrown on other thread will not be caught by that code.

Comment: which line is the error thrown?

Comment: Not all exceptions are recoverable. suppose this exception occurs, it breaks out of your code and goes to the handler. where should your program resume?

Comment: @AlexeiLenenkov: Ah ok thanks I understand! But here it can't be the stack because my program works when I set the right permissions. So there is no possibility to prevent such a program from crashing?!?

Comment: @FahadJameel: That's the Problem, I can't see it because there is nothing in the stack trace but These lines are the ONLY calls to the library so it must be there

Comment: @CThin: Ok I understand that Point! But if I want to write e.g. a Service application then I can't prevent it from crashing? I can't believe that.

Comment: Well, the idea of forcing an application to continue after any exception is typically seen as a poor decision. That said, I understand that its something you could want. could you simply relaunch an instance of your service in your exception handler? this would prevent bad states from carrying.

Comment: @CThin: Yes you are right and I know that. The Problem with the relaunch is that it NEVER reaches my exception handler. That's actually my Problem. It just crashes.

Comment: What if you wrap all the code above in a `try/catch`, and don't put anything in the catch?

Comment: @gunr2171: Sorry, the "do something and write to log" was somehow confusing. I changed it. Actually I don't do anything. I'm just writing to log (stdout) that an error happened.

Answer (score 4):

```
Error : System.Exception: Failed to retrieve file listing: Access to the path...
```

Well, this is a **managed exception** and you should be able to catch it, period. Duplicati is using Interop to native libraries, and a failure in that call is where the call stack beings, but it is unwinding and propagating through the managed call stack.

I wrote a really quick Duplicati example and it catches all the exceptions...

**No exception:**

```
mono HelloDup.exe "/tmp"
File: Local folder or drive
```

**Exception caught:**

```
ls /home/private/privateinfo
ls: : Permission denied
mono HelloDup.exe "/home/private/privateinfo"
Exception: Access to the path "/home/private/privateinfo" is denied.: Type:System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

**Exception caught:**

```
mono HelloDup.exe "/foobar"
Exception: The folder /foobar does not exist: Type:Duplicati.Library.Interface.FolderMissingException
```

**Exception caught:**

```
ls -l /noperms/private.txt
--w-------  1 root  wheel  0 Jun 25 14:16 /noperms/private.txt
mono HelloDup.exe "/noperms/private.txt"
Exception: The folder /noperms/private.txt does not exist: Type:Duplicati.Library.Interface.FolderMissingException
```

**Code example:**

```
try {
    var file = new Duplicati.Library.Backend.File(args[0], options);
    file.CreateFolder();
    Console.WriteLine ("File: {0}", file.DisplayName);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Exception: {0}: Type:{1}", e.Message, e.GetType());
}
```

**Next Steps:**

I would check the versions of Mono and Duplicati you are using... If you are a base system install of Mono, you could be really behind the times. Also I used xbuild to compile Duplicati so I'm using the HEAD of the GitHub master branch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I copy your exact code example and Change the path to my Folder than I'm also able to catch the Exception! But NOT when I use the Interface class. I guess the difference here is that by using `Backend.File` the Exception is directly caught but when using `Interface` the exception is thrown in an other thread.

Comment: Interesting. Which version of mono are you using? (mono --version), also which archtecture? x86 or amd64/x86_64?  Also interop calling into C vs C++ will result in different exception handing as C does not have exception handing while C++ can, but it is different than managed exception...it gets tricky fast ;-)

Comment: I'm using mono version 3.2.8. My architecture is ARMv6 (Raspberry :-)) Maybe that's the problem here! Yeah, getting very tricky...

Answer (score 2):

**The `catch` block is throwing an exception perhaps**?

Anyway, A variation of @gunr2171 idea - create a separate Vis. Studio project with a single file (class) and all it does is call the main program wrapped in `try/catch`; so this is at the very top of the application.

If your library is threaded it should expose a something for testing for a thread-exception; much like the [`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

**Register with the AppDomain.UnhandledException event**

[A simple tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/668/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions)

---

**Worthwhile exception catching**

Make liberal use of the `Exception.Data` property. Sometimes I override `ToString()` in my classes expressly for the purpose of throwing that into `Exception.Data`.

Catch narrowly as practicable in the body of the application (which it seems the OP has done). This context will help you capture particularly relevant information in `Exception.Data`. Read the library's - and .NET - documentation.

Have a universal `try/catch` at the top of the application.

Avoid layers of re-catching that doesn't add context.

*Re-Throwing:*  `throw e` drops the stack trace up to that point. `throw` instead.

---

**Make your application robust**

- Define default state. [The null object pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/null-object-pattern.html)
- Force clients to use your constructors. Don't expose properties and expect clients to properly initialize. [Alan Kay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay) said emphatically that exposing properties (state) is not object oriented programming.
- I hate `null` strings. Here is my favorite line of real-live production code:  `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString.Trim()))`

---

**Some hopefully helpful links**

- [Recursive re-attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access)

  - Marc Gravell chimes in here.
  - " flaws of the GetDirectories() method."
- [Access to the path denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-denied)

  - Marc Gravell answers
  - Setting program to run as Administrator
- [Catching Unhandled exceptions on separate threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284986/catching-unhandled-exception-on-separate-threads)

  - Has further links to unhandled exception stuff.