# How to fix catching TimeoutException?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timeoutexception

How can I catch `TimeoutException`?

I want to catch `TimeoutException` after 3 secs.
But after 3 secs it prints out `TimeoutException` whereas `It's too long. Timeout!` is expected.

With `console application` it doesn't catch `TimeoutException`.

```
public static void work()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("TimeoutException");
    throw new TimeoutException();
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ThreadStart th = new ThreadStart(work);
        Thread t = new Thread(th);
        t.Start();
        //Execute SearchProgram
        t.Abort();
    }
    catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's too long. Timeout!");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Result : ~~~");
}
```

Comment: You're catching `ThreadInterruptedException` and not `TimeoutException`

Comment: You threw `TimeoutException();` inside your `work` method and expecting to catch `ThreadInterruptedException`?

Comment: [Catching unhandled exception on separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284986/catching-unhandled-exception-on-separate-threads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have been able to say you do not catch the good exception. But this is not the expected answer since the error of one thread can not be catched from another.

There are several ways to handle this case, which can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5983851/11608449).

An example for your case:

```
public static void work()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("TimeoutException");
    throw new TimeoutException();
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => SafeExecute(() => work(), Handler));
    thread.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Result : ~~~");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void Handler(Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
}

private static void SafeExecute(Action test, Action<Exception> handler)
{
    try
    {
        test.Invoke();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's too long. Timeout!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Handler(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably catching the wrong exception. According to the microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.timeoutexception?view=netframework-4.8) you should catch the TimeOutException class.